# How to style Next.js active link with Styled Components

Tags: javascript, next.js, styled-components

I'm trying to add a style to the active link with styled components.

I have a navbar and depending on which link is currently active, the respective link will have a style added to it

Thanks

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { bool } from 'prop-types';
import StyledSidebar from '../../styles/header/styled.sidebar'
import StyledLink from '../../styles/header/styled.links'


export default function Sidebar({ open }) {
    const router = useRouter()

    return (
        <StyledSidebar open={open}>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <StyledLink><Link href="/" className={router.pathname == "/" ? 'active' : ''}>HOME</Link></StyledLink>
                    <StyledLink><Link href="/destination" className={router.pathname == "/destination" ? 'active' : ''}>DESTINATION</Link></StyledLink>
                    <StyledLink><Link href="/crew" className={router.pathname == "/crew" ? 'active' : ''}>CREW</Link></StyledLink>
                    <StyledLink><Link href="/technology" className={router.pathname == "/" ? 'active' : ''}>TECHNOLOGY</Link></StyledLink>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </StyledSidebar>
    )
}

Sidebar.propTypes = {
    open: bool.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: <StyledLink pathname={router.pathname}><Link href="/" className={router.pathname == "/" ? 'active' : ''}>HOME</Link></StyledLink> pass it like that

Comment: Let me know if that works. I'll explain in answer in detail

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do i use a styled component to change the style of the active link with this method?

Answer (score 1):

Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-kilby-eb3pj?file=/src/App.js:0-584 link where you see this logic live

Pass the props to styled-components as normal props restructure and use it for conditionally render the styles

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

// props which are received are destructured
const Button = styled.button(
  ({ someprops }) => css`
    ${console.log(someprops)}
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 0.25em 1em;
    border-radius: 3px;
// Conditionally render the styles inside style
    color: ${someprops === "root" ? "red" : "green"};
    border: 2px solid ${someprops === "root" ? "red" : "green"};
  `
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button someprops="root">Themed</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Almost there, now I just need to add the style depending which link is clicked. It works for one, but I need it to work for all of them. I tried  border-right: 3px solid ${props === "/destination" ? "white" : "transparent" } too but it only works for one at a time.

Comment: This is an approach you have to tweak it make it work. Please this accept as an answer if that works